# using gzip files in Data Crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have gzip files in a S3 Bucket. They are not CSV files , they are text files with columns separated by space . I am new using Glue and it Is some way to use Glue - Data Crawler to read this content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glue is just Spark under the hood. So you can just use the same spark code to process the space delimited file i.e. splitBy etc. Glue Crawler will create the metadata for the table by parsing the data. If your data is space separated, then Glue crawler won't be able to parse it. It will basically consider the whole line as one single text column. To process it, you will need to write a custom classifier using Grok pattern. Unfortunately there is no clear example provided in AWS documentation. I am giving an example below:

Assuming your data is like below: (it can be in the gzip file as well)

qwe 123 22.3 2019-09-02

asd 123 12.3 2019-09-02

de3 345 23.3 2019-08-22

we3 455 12.3 2018-08-11

ccc 543 12.0 2017-12-12

1. First you have to create a custom classifier

Grok Pattern

%{NOTSPACE:name} %{INT:class_num} %{BASE10NUM:balance} %{CUSTOMDATE:balance_date}

Custom patterns

CUSTOMDATE %{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}

2. Now create a crawler using the custom classifier you just created. Run the crawler. Then check the metadata created in your database to see if it has recognised the data properly.

Please let me know if any question. You can also share few lines from the file you are trying to process.

If you are new to Glue and keen to try, you may like to read the blog I have written in LinkedIn regarding Glue. Please click this [link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/my-top-5-gotchas-working-aws-glue-tanveer-uddin/).